# Remove R-base in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dpkg, uninstall, r

I got some errors while trying to install R-studio in Ubuntu 16.04, because R-base was not properly installed, so I wanted to delete R-base and re-install it. I tried several solutions mentioned in other threads, but they didn't work. The same error keeps popping up.

For example when I use this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge r-base-core
```

I get the following error (which also pops up with other commands for removal):

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   The following packages will be removed:
>   r-base-core* r-base-dev* r-base-html* r-cran-boot* r-cran-class* r-cran-cluster*
>   r-cran-codetools* r-cran-foreign* r-cran-kernsmooth*   r-cran-lattice*
>   r-cran-mass* r-cran-matrix* r-cran-mgcv* r-cran-nlme*  r-cran-nnet*
>   r-cran-rpart* r-cran-spatial* r-cran-survival* r-recommended*
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 19 to remove and 337 not upgraded.  1 not
>   fully installed or removed.
>   After this operation, 57.0 MB disk space will be freed.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
>
> Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
>   /usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 1: /etc/default/locale: -e: not found
>   dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
>   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>   install-info E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: try `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst.old` followed by update and upgrade

Comment: @luchonacho When I do that, it says  `mv: missing destination file operand after '/var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst'`.